# Why am I struggling to center my table for small screens only? (<480px)

Tags: html, css

I know the code will center the table without the media query, but what's going wrong here that is causing it to not center it for less than 480px?

CSS:

```
<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 480px){
 .beta {margin:0px auto;}
 .rwd-break { display: none; }
 }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<table class="beta">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">TITLE HERE</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="1"><b>16' x 36'</td>
<td>576 ft.²</td>
<td>$38,750</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>16' x 40'</td>
<td>640 ft.²</td>
<td>$39,900</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In your CSS you have `.table` as the classname instead of using `.beta` or just `table` to define it for the HTML tag

Comment: But even if I remove the "." and just make it table or make it ".beta", it still doesn't center the table under 480p.

Comment: When you do `min-width: xxx` it comes out as `> xxx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this ? [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42jne6tp/3/)

```
   @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
     .beta {margin:0px auto;}
     .rwd-break { display: none; }
   }
```

Use `max-width` instead of `min-width` to center table under 480px.

Comment: Okay, yeah, I updated my post to correct that stupid error, but I don't want the table to be centered all the time, just under 480px width.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that last bit. You are correct.